# Regular expression for replacing extra characters between markers

Tags: c#, .net, regex, regex-lookarounds

Suppose i have some sample text like below:

```
;&nbsp; </span>&lt;year&gt;<o:p></o:p>
</span>&lt;</span><span style=3D'font-size:9.0pt;mso-bidi-font-family:Arial'>manufacturer&gt;</span><span                  style=3D'mso-bidi-font-family:Arial'>
</span>&lt;model&gt;<o:p>
</span>&lt;<span class=3DSpellE>serial_number</span>&gt;<o:p>
</span>&lt;<span class=3DSpellE>accessories_value</span>&gt;<o:p></o:p></span>
</span>&lt;<span class=3DSpellE>accessories_list</span>&gt;
p;&nbsp; </span>&lt;<span class=3DSpellE>worldwide_yn</span>&gt;
</span>&lt;</b><span class=3DSpellE><span style=3D'mso-no-proof:yes'>pet_name</span></span><span style=3D'mso-   no-proof:yes'>&gt;</span><o:p></o:p></p>
```

I am looking to find and replace every occurrences of following pattern:

```
&lt; any_html_tags markers_text any_html_tags &gt;
```

Here :

html_tags: optional, may be both opening and closing type, may be zero to many times in numbers, there may be any HTML marker here.

markers_text: can be in one of two formats as either xxxxx (any no. of characters) or xxxx_xxxxxx (text can be of any length).

like i want to be able to find following texts in sample file:

```
1) &lt;year&gt;
2) &lt;</span><span style=3D'font-size:9.0pt;mso-bidi-font-family:Arial'>manufacturer&gt;
3) &lt;model&gt;
4) &lt;<span class=3DSpellE>serial_number</span>&gt;
5) &lt;<span class=3DSpellE>accessories_value</span>&gt;
6) &lt;<span class=3DSpellE>accessories_list</span>&gt;
7) &lt;<span class=3DSpellE>worldwide_yn</span>&gt;
8) &lt;</b><span class=3DSpellE><span style=3D'mso-no-proof:yes'>pet_name</span></span><span style=3D'mso-no-proof:yes'>&gt;
```

and replace them with corresponding items like:

```
1) &lt;year&gt;
2) </span><span style=3D'font-size:9.0pt;mso-bidi-font-family:Arial'>&lt;manufacturer&gt;
3) &lt;model&gt;
4) <span class=3DSpellE></span>&lt;serial_number&gt;
5) <span class=3DSpellE></span>&lt;accessories_value&gt;
6) <span class=3DSpellE></span>&lt;accessories_list&gt;
7) <span class=3DSpellE></span>&lt;worldwide_yn&gt;
8) </b><span class=3DSpellE><span style=3D'mso-no-proof:yes'></span></span><span style=3D'mso-no-proof:yes'>&lt;pet_name&gt;
```

So basically i want that between &lt ; and &gt ; every tag except MARKER_TEXT gets removed and come before &lt ;
and i am doing it using c# Regex methods.

Can you Please suggest Proper Regular Expression to achieve it?

Final sample Result should look like:

```
;&nbsp; </span>&lt;year&gt;<o:p></o:p>
</span></span><span style=3D'font-size:9.0pt;mso-bidi-font-family:Arial'>&lt;manufacturer&gt;</span><span     style=3D'mso-bidi-font-family:Arial'>
 </span>&lt;model&gt;<o:p>
 </span><span class=3DSpellE></span>&lt;serial_number&gt;<o:p>
 </span><span class=3DSpellE></span>&lt;accessories_value&gt;<o:p></o:p></span>
  </span><span class=3DSpellE></span>&lt;accessories_list&gt;
 p;&nbsp; </span><span class=3DSpellE></span>&lt;worldwide_yn&gt;
</b><span class=3DSpellE><span style=3D'mso-no-proof:yes'></span></span><span style=3D'mso-no-  proof:yes'>&lt;pet_name&gt;
```

Comment: The 2nd example doesn't fit your description.

Comment: @Casimir et Hippolyte Updating the Query

Answer (score 1):

This search/replace is probably what you are looking for:

pattern:

```
&lt;((?:</?span[^>]*>)*)(\w+)((?:</?span[^>]*>)*)&gt;
```

replacement:

```
$1&lt;$2&gt;$3
```

[online demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%26lt%3B((%3F%3A%3C%2F%3Fspan%5B%5E%3E%5D*%3E)*)(%5Cw%2B)((%3F%3A%3C%2F%3Fspan%5B%5E%3E%5D*%3E)*)%26gt%3B&i=%3B%26nbsp%3B%20%3C%2Fspan%3E%26lt%3Byear%26gt%3B%3Co%3Ap%3E%3C%2Fo%3Ap%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Fspan%3E%26lt%3B%3C%2Fspan%3E%3Cspan%20style%3D3D%27font-size%3A9.0pt%3Bmso-bidi-font-family%3AArial%27%3Emanufacturer%26gt%3B%3C%2Fspan%3E%3Cspan%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20style%3D3D%27mso-bidi-font-family%3AArial%27%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Fspan%3E%26lt%3Bmodel%26gt%3B%3Co%3Ap%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Fspan%3E%26lt%3B%3Cspan%20class%3D3DSpellE%3Eserial_number%3C%2Fspan%3E%26gt%3B%3Co%3Ap%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Fspan%3E%26lt%3B%3Cspan%20class%3D3DSpellE%3Eaccessories_value%3C%2Fspan%3E%26gt%3B%3Co%3Ap%3E%3C%2Fo%3Ap%3E%3C%2Fspan%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Fspan%3E%26lt%3B%3Cspan%20class%3D3DSpellE%3Eaccessories_list%3C%2Fspan%3E%26gt%3B%0D%0Ap%3B%26nbsp%3B%20%3C%2Fspan%3E%26lt%3B%3Cspan%20class%3D3DSpellE%3Eworldwide_yn%3C%2Fspan%3E%26gt%3B&r=%241%26lt%3B%242%26gt%3B%243)*(see the "Context tab")*

Comment: Thanks @Casimir et Hippolyte

Comment: @rene i understand it ... but it is true :-(

Comment: Your edit renders this answer obsolete. Don't become a [help vampire](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19665/the-help-vampire-problem) and don't try to parse html with [regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/578411).  Consider if a new question is more appropiate where you use this answer as a starting point that shows your own effort.